# Get json field value using regex in c#

Tags: c#, json, regex

I get a json result from service, and want to get its values by regex.
How can I do it?
this is my json:

```
{"success":true,
"transaction":{"id":"82631130",
"balanceAfter":"8555"}}
```

Comment: The question referenced is not an exact duplicate of this question, because this question asks specifically for a regex to extract values.

Comment: There should be a RegExStackExchange and JsonStackExchange and when you create your first question it says, DO NOT PARSE HTML OR JSON WITH REGEX. 1000 questions a week would instantly vanish